how can I send from a child contract by main contract?
I have a contract like this:
contract Child {
    receive() external payable {}
}

contract Mother {
    function deployChildContracts(uint256  salts) external {
deploy(type(Child).creationCode, bytes32(salts));
      
    }
}

I can call deployChildContracts function and have many child contract.
As far as I know, I can put a function in child contract like this:
function sendMain(uint256 _amount, address payable _receiver) external {
_receiver.transfer(_amount);
    }

and then, call sendMain from per child contract for transfer ETH to other account.
But I don't want to put this function inside per child, I would like to transfer ETH from per child to other address from mother. actually I need a function in mother like this:
 function safeTransferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 amount) external {
        ETH.safeTransferFrom(from, to, amount);
    }

something like delegate transfer from child to others by mother contract.
anybody can help me?


But I don't want to put this function inside per child, I would like to transfer ETH from per child to other address from mother. actually I need a function in mother like this:

You can't pull ETH from another contract, there's no equivalent to transferFrom for ERC20 tokens with ETH. You'd have to call the function child contract somehow. You probably want a function in your child contract that can only be called by mother, and a function in mother that  makes the call.
Something like:

contract Child {
    address mom;
    constructor() {
        mom = msg.sender; // Records the deployer, which is the mother contract
    }
    function executeTransfer(address to, uint amount) external {
        require(msg.sender == mom);
        payable(to).transfer(amount);
    }

}
contract Mother {
    function deployChildContracts(uint256  salts) external {
deploy(type(Child).creationCode, bytes32(salts));
    }
    function transferFromChild(address _child, address to, uint256 amount) {
        Child(_child).executeTransfer(to, amount);
    }

}

